# How to get Authorization Code using Identity Server 4 Authorization Code Grant Type Flow

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am using dotnet core (.NET Core) 3.1 with the IdentityServer4 package. I have an SPA that I wish to integrate with Identity Server 4 so I am going down the path of using the **Authorization Code** grant type using PKCE. I understand the basic idea of this grant type however I don't understand how to exchange the username/password for an **Authorization Code**. Here is how I understand it.

1. The SPA makes a GET request to /authorize endpoint that looks something like `http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize?client_id=js&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5003/callback.html&response_type=code&scope=openid profile api1&state=8636d5233f77413584799be6cafe03a7&code_challenge=FbNm1tMkaRMzcSBv4_d5Rpq4VNaqyINVkCAcHsZkKV0&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=query`
2. This returns a 302 redirect to http://localhost:5000/Account/Login that I assume should be a login screen hosted by the auth server.
3. The user submits their credentials, the auth server validates the credentials and returns another 302 redirect to the given redirect_url, http://localhost:5003/callback.html in this case. The redirect url should include the generated **Authorization Code** and provided State in the query string.
4. The SPA validates the State and then makes a request to the /token endpoint that includes in the header: authorization=Basic Y2xpZW50OnNlY3JldA== and in the query string: grant_type=authorization_code, code=**Authorization Code**, redirect_uri=http://localhost/redirect
5. The auth server returns a valid token.

I've done steps 1 and 2 (no UI yet but that's not important yet). Calling the /authorize is working. I'm getting a valid 302 response. Where I'm stuck is steps 3 and 4. Am I required to write an endpoint that generates an **Authorization Code** and returns the 302 redirect containing it or is this something that is already built into Identity Server 4 (like the /authorize and /token endpoints)?

I have mashed a number of examples I've found online including this one https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/4_javascript_client.html. There doesn't seem to be any complete examples using this type of grant type. I have also included in my startup a few test resources, clients and users.

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetAllApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
    .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());
```

Thanks for any help you can provide to at least push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [quickstart](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/3_AspNetCoreAndApis). In particular, the [login action](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/3a7547d2df9fc178c0e62ea0ca4441e6028eba74/samples/Quickstarts/3_AspNetCoreAndApis/src/IdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L78) in Account controller that validates credentials.

There are 2 important steps:

1. [Sign in](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/3a7547d2df9fc178c0e62ea0ca4441e6028eba74/samples/Quickstarts/3_AspNetCoreAndApis/src/IdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L130) to Identity Server (throught cookie by default)
2. [Redirect](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/3a7547d2df9fc178c0e62ea0ca4441e6028eba74/samples/Quickstarts/3_AspNetCoreAndApis/src/IdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L138) to [view](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/3a7547d2df9fc178c0e62ea0ca4441e6028eba74/samples/Quickstarts/3_AspNetCoreAndApis/src/IdentityServer/Views/Shared/Redirect.cshtml) that loads [this javascript](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/3a7547d2df9fc178c0e62ea0ca4441e6028eba74/samples/Quickstarts/3_AspNetCoreAndApis/src/IdentityServer/wwwroot/js/signin-redirect.js) for better experience in case of PKCE. The url contains query parameters *code* and *state* that are generated and managed by Identity server.

Comment: From my comment in the previous answer, I hadn't considered using the templates. I'll take a look at these and see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

for step number 3, you do need to come out with ui/endpoint for user login

The IdentityServer4 team make this easy by creating a template that you can just import
here is the link of the template - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Templates

in you case, i think you need is4ui template

Comment: I hadn't considered using the templates instead have been referring to the documentation and examples. Will run through a few of these to get an idea on how they achieve this.